# why i failing when i trying to recording phone call

Tags: android, audio-recording

I wrote a code that recording from the microphone and it work fine. 
But new i changed the code and i trying to do a recording the phone call - but when i start the recording i somehow get an error and my application is return an exit

someone can tell me what i doing wrong ? 
The permission are ok - i add all needed permission i needed. 
This it android marshmallow.

The code:

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileNameGenerator());

    try
    {
        recorder.prepare();     
        recorder.start();           // after this line - the app is exit 
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is it printing some log?

Comment: no, just stop the app. there is no exception

Comment: do you add permission in manifest?

Comment: yes, i wrote in my question .. all needed permission are in